# Error creating applicationContext.xml: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, javabeans

I'm trying to configurate a Java MVC webapp with Spring and Hibernate, but when I run the server I have this error, and I don't know what's the problem.

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:546)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:872)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2283)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2279)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1748)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1788)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1409)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate connection provider [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider]
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:176)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider cannot be cast to org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:189)
    ... 43 more
jul 27, 2013 10:38:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Excepción enviando evento inicializado de contexto a instancia de escuchador de clase org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:546)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:872)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
```

This is my applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


    <!-- holding properties for database connectivity /-->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>

    <!-- enabling annotation driven configuration /-->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.companyname.springapp.repository" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.companyname.springapp.service" />

</beans>
```

In my jdbc.properties, I have this information, in addition to the url, username and password of the database.

```
hibernate.generate_statistics = true
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbcDriver
```

I have all this jar to load the classes. Something of them (like jpa-api.jar) I think it's not neccesary, but I had it in other project from which I begin to make this, and I didn't remove it yet:

```
activation-1.1.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-pool-1.6.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.1.8.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.8.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-4.0.2.GA.jar
hibernate3.jar
javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
javax.mail.jar
jaxb-api-2.1.jar
jaxb-impl-2.1.3.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.0.GA.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
jpa-api-2.0-cr-1.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
junit-4.8.1.jar
log4j-1.2.14.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar
org.apache.commons.dbcp.jar
org.springframework.orm.jar
postgresql-8.4-701.jdbc4.jar
servlet-api-2.5.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.11.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.11.jar
spring-aop-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-asm-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
stax-api-1.0-2.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
```

Someone can help me with this trouble?
I run it in Eclipse with Tomcat 7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your log hints "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider cannot be cast to org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider"

It seems that you're using Hibernate4 with spring-hibernate3-support:

hibernate-core-4.1.8.Final.jar

org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean